# Simulate hidden form submit & redirect with JavaScript for secure payment

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I am creating a secure payment system in a SPA application and the process I currently use is:

CREATE HIDDEN FORM -> FILL FORM WITH DATA -> SUBMIT FORM && REDIRECT USER TO 3RD PARTY SECURE PAYMENT GATEWAY

I was wondering if there is a way with JavaScript or jQuery to **simulate a form submit+redirect**, without creating a hidden form, because this solution feels a little "dirty". 
Ajax request is not an option here, because of cross origin restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Simulate? You can trigger one, sure.

jQuery:

```
$('#myformelement').submit();
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myformelement').submit();
```

Comment: I do need to trigger a form submit, but to simulate the way the browser redirects the user to the form's action, along with the form data, when the user submits a form.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by Simulate. You could see all the traffic going from/to the browser with a tool such as Fiddler. Or are you trying to automate something that should post data when something happens?

Answer (score 0):

add id or class in form tag

```
<form id="form1" ...>
```

change submit button to anchor

```
<a id="submitAnchor"> ... </a>
```

and in jQuery submit the form and redirect the user as well

```
$("#submitAnchor").click(function(){
            $(".form1").submit();
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = 'your URL';
            }, 1000);
        });
```